# as rptr->num=30 is same as (*rptr).num=30 but*((*rptr).ptr).name does not work why?

Tags: c++

I have two structures

```
struct temp
{
   char name[20];
};

struct abc
{
  temp *ptr;
  int num;
};
```

Here is the main function.

```
main()
{
   abc *rptr;
   strcpy((rptr->ptr)->name,"Wellcome");
   cout<<(rptr->ptr)->name; //works
   cout<<*((*rptr).ptr).name; //does not work why?
}
```

I would like to know why the last `cout` does not work.

Comment: One * is inside () other is outside - So they are not doing same thing

Comment: I cut and pasted this code into by IDE but it did not compile. Could it be that it's not really an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Why not just paste the complete program, with `#include` statements?

Comment: You need `(*(*` at the start, not `*((*`.

Comment: yes it does not compile  because of the last statement *((*rptr).ptr).name.

Comment: yes ,(* (*rptr).ptr).name works but please explain why it works i am still confused.

Comment: Why are you using `char` arrays and `strcpy` in a *C++* program? What's wrong with `std::string`? Also; `main` returns `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
cout << *((*rptr).ptr).name;
```

Doesn't work because the action `.` on `((*rptr).ptr)` has higher precedence than the `*`

Fix it using:

```
cout << (*((*rptr).ptr)).name;
```

**Important**

Please note that your code has a bigger issues in it:

- You are writing to an uninitialized **pointer** `rptr`
- Your struct `abc` contains a **pointer** to `temp`, **not** an **instance**!

Doing this: `strcpy((rptr->ptr)->name,"Wellcome");` is considered a **crime**! You are corrupting all of your memory!

Instead, it should look like this:

```
abc *rptr = new abc();
rptr->ptr = new temp();

strncpy(rptr->ptr->name, "Wellcome", sizeof(rptr->ptr->name));
cout << rptr->ptr->name << endl;

delete rptr->ptr;
delete rptr;
```

Fixes:

- Allocate `rptr` object
- Allocate `ptr` object inside your `rptr`
- Copy the "Wellcome" string carefully (Add bounds checking)

Comment: Rather than raw `new` I'd suggest using smart pointers. Naked `new`/`delete` is *very* rarely the right choice. But this code really just wants to use `std::string` anyway...

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I agree with you 101% :) But since the user seems to find pointer concepts still confusing, I wanted to emphasize the need to initialize dynamically allocated objects. Though, I sure will add `delete`-s to my answer!

Comment: Rather than adding explicit `delete`s, why not show how `std::unique_ptr`/`std::make_unique` removes the need for them? Teach the better way :-)

Comment: One thing I remember someone saying recently that really struck home with me is that pointers should be an intermediate level topic in C++, not a beginner level topic like it needs to be in C. People shouldn't be messing with pointers until they know how to do all the basic stuff (strings, vectors, lists, etc...) with the standard library types.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because of precedence rules. `.` (structure member selection) has a higher binding than `*` (pointer dereference). Put in some parenthesis and it'd work just fine. Notice how you put parenthesis around the inner pointer dereference, why did you skip the outer?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer you accepted was an excellent answer that told you how to fix what you were doing and why it wasn't working.

This answer is to tell you what you should be doing instead. Because what you are doing is not really C++. In modern C++ it should be uncommon that you ever have to deal with pointers. And this is a huge advantage that C++ has over C, and one of the chief reasons to choose the language in my opinion.

Here's how your two structures should look:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct temp
{
   ::std::string name;
};

struct abc
{
   ::std::unique_ptr<temp> ptr;
   int num;
};
```

And here's how your main should've looked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // Probably redundant, but you do use it directly here.

int main()
{
    using ::std::unique_ptr;
    using ::std::cout;
    using ::std::make_unique;

    // If you don't have make_unique (it was added in C++14) use new instead.
    unique_ptr<abc> rptr = make_unique<abc>();
    rptr->ptr = make_unique<temp>();

    rptr->ptr->name = "Wellcome";
    cout << (rptr->ptr)->name;
    cout << (*(*rptr).ptr).name;
    return 0;
}
```

The `unique_ptr` objects will automatically free the things they're pointing at when they go out of scope. So, first `rptr` goes away and so the `abc` it points to is destroyed, and this will destroy the `ptr` member of `abc` which will result in the `temp` you allocated also being freed.

Yes, those are technically pointers, but the compiler will manage their lifetime for you so that you don't have leaks or accidentally free something twice.

Also, using `::std::string` means you don't have to worry about unsafe operations like `strcpy` and `strlen` at all. It will just work.

Now, presumably your program was just an example, and you have a larger program that you're actually working on. But these principles are the same. Do not use bare pointers unless you absolutely have to. Use the C++ pointer classes. They are your friends and will make life much easier for you. Use `::std::string`, `::std::vector`, `::std::array`, and other similar classes from the standard library. They will make your life a lot easier.